# Computing homology groups of glued hexagon

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, homology-cohomology

I've just started studying about homology groups, and I got an exercise in computing the homology groups of the following hexagon, with all edges identified as in the picture:
[image]

The first thing I did is representing it as a $\Delta$-complex as follows:

[image]

I then proceed in computing the chain groups:
$$C_0=\langle v\rangle =\mathbb{Z}$$
$$C_1=\langle a,b,c,d\rangle =\mathbb{Z}^4$$
$$C_2=\langle M,N,P,Q\rangle =\mathbb{Z}^4$$
$$C_n=\{0\}, n\geq3$$

Since there is only one simplex of dimension $0$ ($v$), we have that $\partial_1=0$. Moreover:
$$\partial_2(M)=b-2a$$
$$\partial_2(N)=c-a-b$$
$$\partial_2(P)=d-a-c$$
$$\partial_2(Q)=-2a-d$$
$$Ker(\partial_2)=\langle -2M+N+P+Q \rangle = \mathbb{Z}$$
So:
$$H_0=\mathbb{Z} $$
$$H_1=\langle a,b,c,d|b-2a=c-a-b=d-a-c=0 \rangle = \langle a|6a=0 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}_6$$
$$H_2= \mathbb{Z}$$
$$H_n=\{0\}, n\geq 3$$

Does this seem okay? This is basically the first time I'm computing the homology group of an unknown space on my own, so I'm a bit unsure about my work. My main concern is about $H_1$ - it turned out to be pretty "simple", while I expected a more complicated group, which makes me think that maybe I've made a mistake.

Anyway, I'd be happy to hear your thoughts about my solution, and generally about how you suggest approaching such problems (what to expect and such).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know about cellular homology, then your space has a CW structure with just one 0-cell, one 1-cell, and one 2-cell, i.e., $C_0 \cong C_1 \cong C_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}$.  The boundary maps are $\partial_1 = 0$ and $\partial_2 = \pm 6$, giving
\begin{align}
H_0 &\cong \mathbb{Z} \\
H_1 &\cong \mathbb{Z}_6 \\
H_i &= 0, \quad i \geq 2.
\end{align}

So I would double-check your calculation of $\ker \partial_2$.

Comment: Thank you. So far I only know of simplicial and singular homology, so I'll try checking my work. Since $H_1$ is the same for both of us, I guess that the boundary maps themselves are probably alright, and I probably just have the wrong computation for $ker(\partial_2)$. To get your result, I need the kernel to be trivial right? Since the image of $\partial_3$ must be trivial.

Comment: Yes, $\ker \partial_2$ is zero.  In particular, $\partial_2(-2M + N +P + Q) = -3b$ in your notation, so that element is not in the kernel.